# How can I use Vim keybinding in Emacs?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, emacs, key-bindings

Is there any plugin/extension for Emacs that allows me to use Vim keybindings?

I'm running emacs on Windows Vista appliance running on a Ubuntu host.

Thanks!

Comment: Down-voting for complete lack of research effort. The most cursory of searches would have turned up relevant results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of VI emulators available. Current versions of GNU Emacs ships with one named 'viper'.

To put Emacs into emulation mode, simply type:

```
M-x viper-mode
```

The viper emulator supports a number of different user levels which provides varying degrees of VI adherence, from the beginner level in which almost no normal Emacs key-bindings are available to more sophisticated levels where there is greater integration between the normal key-bindings and the VI way.

To get out of the viper emulator (always a common issue for me with VI :-), type

```
M-x viper-go-away
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil ?

> Evil is an extensible vi layer for Emacs. It provides Vim features like Visual selection and text objects, and is the successor to Vimpulse and vim-mode.

Comment: Evil would probably be a better option than Viper